# It is possible config a VM instance on GCP to only receive requests from the Load Balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have an nginx deployment on k8s that is exposed via a nodeport service. Is it possible by using the GCP firewall to permit that only an application LB can talk with these nodeports?

I wouldn't like to let these two nodeports opened to everyone.

Comment: I think that all your nodes should be on a private network. But yes, there should probably be firewall rules from LB to all nodes, but it also depends on how you use VPC for your cluster.

Comment: I know that [this service](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy) exists. But I never tested it. Does it address your use case?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @guillaume, but I am not using GKE, only a single VM instance as a k8s node, so this is not applicable in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you can controll access traffics to your VM instance via firewall.

That is why firewall service exitsts.

If you created a VM in the default VPC and firewall setting environment, firewall will deny all traffics from outside.

You just need to write a rule to allow traffic from the application LB.

According to [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-http-lb-simple#firewall), You need to allow from `130.211.0.0/22` and `35.191.0.0/16` IP ranges.

Comment: Thank you @kallusis369. I tried these ranges yesterday but I think I didn't give enough time to the LB to proceed with the health checks on the backend. You are right and now is working perfectly.

Comment: @DanielMarques There is nothing to stop someone from creating a Google Cloud Load Balancer, adding a NEG and then specifying your backend public IP address. You are allowing any service running on those IP addresses.

Comment: Yeah @John Hanley, I just realized that this range is too open, I already tried to define only the LB IP, but isn't working.